# PHP error when variables have utf8 values

Tags: php, apache

I have problems with php when variables are assigned utf8 values. For example, I have 2 scripts:

```
script1:
<?php
$var = "джиган";
echo '<a href="test2.php?var='.$var.'">test</a>';
?>

script2:
<?php
$var = $_GET['var'];
echo $var;
?>
```

Edit:
I do not think the error is with displaying in browser, so methods like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

do not work. I have tested above scripts on 2 servers: on localhost and on shared hosting. Problem occurs on shared hosting. I guess the problem with server configurations.

When I call script 2 from link in script 1 my server gives me the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /agayan/test2.php on this server.
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: are you sure when you assign `utf8` values at that time it is not working?

Comment: Agreed. I would create a utf-8 test to make sure that it is in fact working/broken.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yes. I have tried with not utf8 values and it works

Comment: @torayeff try with setting encoding of page with `utf8`. and check wether it is working or not.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I have added <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> to htmls. Still it does not work

Comment: @torayeff try with `php's` content type setting.

Comment: That is an Apache server error, that should not relate to the PHP code. Make sure your permissions for `/agayan` and `test2.php` are set correctly. If they are check your Apache error log to see if it gives anymore information about the error.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i guess it is not error with displaying

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you

```
<?php
        $var = "джиган";
        echo '<a href="test2.php?var='.$var.'">test</a>';
?>
```

and your second script should be

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        $var = $_GET['var'];
        echo $var;
?>
```

and your global directory settings should be like  (httpd.conf line ~188):

```
<Directory />

            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Comment: It did not work. I do not think it is error with displaying in browser, I guess the error is with server.

Comment: see the setting of your httpd.conf file